# Importing a .bundle for iOS with executable code

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, bundle, coreml

I am trying to make an application in Objective C where a user can download a .mlmodel file from Google Drive and then dynamically load this model as a class and run its methods that come from CoreML's MLModel interface.

Looking at Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Concepts/AboutLoadableBundles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001268-BCIDBAEJ), it appears I should be able to do this using bundles: "You can make your application extensible by designing a plug-in architecture. This way, you or third-party developers can easily add new features without recompiling the whole application or even having access to its source code."

My existing code downloads their .mlmodel file from Google Drive and saves it to the Documents folder. However, not finding a way to instantiate this as a class, I switched approaches, and will instead download a .bundle file from their Google Drive and then try to make the class from the files within it. I am struggling to find any examples of how to do this. First, I do not know how to get a .bundle file after making an App, setting the principal class, and setting the BundleID as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Tasks/CreatingBundles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001274-CJBDDCAB). Second, I am concerned that although the documentation seems to indicate that what I want to achieve is possible, I have run across several SO posts that say that running any sort of uncompiled code, dynamically linked code is impossible on iOS. I would appreciate any clarity on the matter.

Comment: This is a Mac function only « For detailed information about how OS X loads and executes code, see Mach-O Runtime Architecture.»

Comment: What you needs seems described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/downloading_and_compiling_a_model_on_the_user_s_device)